# Java code to convert google drive spreadsheet to excel

Tags: java, google-drive-api

Need Java Code to convert Google Drive Spreadsheet to Excel. Later I want to send the converted file as mail attachment.

I am using this code to retrieve the file metadata -

```
services.files().get(fileObj.getId()).executeAsInputStream();
```

I have a code to send the mail, but the problem is if I use the above code, the attachment is like a link to Google Drive document.

Answer (score 0):

The [`File`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files) object has `exportLinks` property that

> "Links for exporting Google Docs to specific formats."

`exportLinks.(key)` can be used to get the link for a specific format. Replace the `key` with the mimeType you want the file exported to (if I remember correctly)

You can find more info about the `exportLinks` keys (and Document Downloading in general) [*here*](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents)